# Getting Error while calculation on variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to calculate the percentage of utilized space for specific folder and display the value compared to a threshold value i.e. 85% but when I write below code, I get error:

> Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo" value of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo" to type "System.Double".

Code:

```
$Path = "C:\Nikhil"
$Workspace = (Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"{0:N2}" -f ($Workspace.sum / 1GB)
$Workspace1 = $Workspace -as [double]
$Percentage = ($Workspace1/6143.87)*100
if($Percentage -le 85)
{
    $body += "`t" + $Path + " is $Percentage percent utilized. "
}
```

Could you please correct me where I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
$Workspace1 = $Workspace -as [double]
```

Should be

```
$Workspace1 = $Workspace.Sum -as [double]
```

Because $Workspace is a measurement object with properties, not a number.

Comment: ++, but it's also worth noting that `.Sum` already _is_ a `[double]`, so there is no need to convert it at all (verify with `(Measure-Object -Sum).Sum.GetType().FullName`).